# Gettings Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,140.82.x.x' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts

Tags: ssh, github

Having some issues with repetitive logs inside nodejs container,

###### this is my flow :

- Nodejs container fetching ssh key(private key)
- Loading it into ssh-agent (`eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" && cp ${key} ~/.ssh/id_rsa`)
- Cloning a git repository using ssh
- Running `git pull` intervals every 1m

##### Error :

Getting `"Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,140.82.x.x' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts"` on each `git pull` command

###### What I tried so far :

- Remove `stdout` from node `execSync` command
- add this to `~/.ssh/config` and restarting `ssh-agent` with `eval`:

```
Host *
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  LogLevel ERROR
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: These are Warnings, do you care about warnings? if so suppress in ssh config.

Comment: I don't - they just pollutes the process logs .. how do suggest to do that ? `LogLevel=ERROR` didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below parameters, but remember in case of issue you might not get any details in such case you need to change log level again.

```
Host *
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  LogLevel quiet
```

Comment: will try this out.should I test it under `Host *` ?
and also does restarting the ssh-agent will be enough to see changes

Comment: `Host *` personally not recommended, please use with specific host ip/name. No need to restart anything.

Comment: will try one last clarification question - should `Host github` should be ok ?
as it happens only with that host

Comment: Though you can get lots of example, but i am using `Host github.com`, again it's based on your use case/configs etc.

Comment: quick update, tried changing the `~/.ssh/config` like you suggested -> still seeing same warnings ..

Comment: and on which level should I have this `config` file ? inside the container on at the host level

Comment: You should try at ssh client host, from where you are doing ssh. Please share ssh config section you tried.

Comment: tried 
`Host github.com UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null LogLevel=quiet`
with no success

Comment: updated my answer, to check elimination method, can you try it?

Comment: found out that `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` was exported as environment variable within the Dockerfile, with `=ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o LogLevel=ERROR` while getting the warnings, `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is a file created within the container holding the private key for auth to github

Comment: quick update : updating the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` with your suggested values solved the issue, thanks.